# Loop the_post_navigation() Wordpress

Tags: php, wordpress

I am trying to loop the_post_navigation() in Wordpress.

I have found an accepted answer at [this stack overflow question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36718287/loop-through-wordpress-the-post-navigation-function)

But I cannot work out **where** to put this or if I am actually editing/replacing existing php.

The navigation exists in the Wordpress default `link-template.php` file in the wp-includes folder but I cannot work out how to apply the solution from the link above or if there is another way.

I tried adding it at the end or in the functions.php file but it breaks my site every time.

Update: I have this working but the first and last post in the loop will not show the title?

Comment: The code in the accepted answer would go directly into the page template for a single post. Check out this [Visual Overview](https://developer.wordpress.org/themes/basics/template-hierarchy/#visual-overview) of the WordPress Template Hierarchy to determine which file in your theme needs updating.

Comment: Yes that worked - It seems obvious now. 

Is there a way to add classes to the previous and next links? I had custom arrows in place prior to getting this to loop using pseudo elements but I cannot target them anymore. Thanks

Comment: Actually this worked!

`function add_class_next_post_link($html){
    $html = str_replace('<a','<a class="next"',$html);
    return $html;
}
add_filter('next_post_link','add_class_next_post_link',10,1);
 
function add_class_previous_post_link($html){
    $html = str_replace('<a','<a class="prev"',$html);
    return $html;
}
add_filter('previous_post_link','add_class_previous_post_link',10,1);`

Comment: Is there any way to retain the actual post names?